# -[NSString writeToFile:] does not change the contents of the file

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, file-io

I'm trying to write to a file "index.html" that I have in my resources. I can load the file with no problem, but I can't seem to write to it. Nothing is showing up as an error, it simply doesn't write. The app doesn't abort or anything, but when I re-load the file nothing has changed.

My writing code:

```
NSBundle *thisBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
NSString *path = [thisBundle pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@""];
[myString writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

My loading code:

```
[myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason that your existing code doesn't overwrite the `index.html` file is that an application can not overwrite its resources.  Apple's [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html) specifically says:

> This is the bundle directory containing the application itself. Do not write anything to this directory. To prevent tampering, the bundle directory is signed at installation time. Writing to this directory changes the signature and prevents your application from launching again.

Instead, write to your documents directory.  You can get the path to the documents directory like this:

```
NSString * docsDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
```

Note that `NSHomeDirectory()` on iOS simple returns the path to your application's bundle.  Once you have the path to the documents directory, you can write to a resource, let's say index.html, as follows:

```
NSString * path = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"index.html"];
[myString writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Note that I changed your `error:` parameter to `nil`.  This will not actually affect anything, but it is common practice to use `nil` to indicate NULL Objective-C objects.

Comment: AHHHH Thankyou sir! You are a life-saver! I never knew you couldn't overwrite resources... Your code works perfectly! let me know if there is anything I can do to repay you! :D

Comment: One note - it is common to use `nil` for obj-c object pointers but the parameter is actually a _pointer_ to an obj-c object pointer (`NSError**`) and people usually use `NULL` there. It doesn't make real difference but I like to see `NULL` when pointers are involved.

Comment: It's a good practice to pass a pointer to a NSError reference, which you can check at runtime to determine whether the call failed, and if it did, why it failed. Initialize the NSError reference to nil, and if it's not nil after the method call, an error occurred:
  
  NSError *err = nil;
  [myString writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
  if (nil != err) { /* handle an error here */}

Answer (score 1):

Try to move your file to Documents Directory before perform the operation this bunch of code makes the work

### .h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSFileManager (NSFileManagerAdds)
+ (NSString*) copyResourceFileToDocuments:(NSString*)fileName withExt:(NSString*)fileExt;
@end
```

### .m

```
#import "NSFileManager + NSFileManagerAdds.h"

@implementation NSFileManager (NSFileManagerAdds)

+ (NSString*) copyResourceFileToDocuments:(NSString*)fileName withExt:(NSString*)fileExt
{
    //Look at documents for existing file
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", fileName, fileExt]];

    NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {
        NSError *nError;
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:fileExt] toPath:path error:&nError];
    }

    return path;
}

@end
```

Finally you should use it in something like that:

```
[NSFileManager copyResourceFileToDocuments:@"index" withExt:@"html"];
```

Comment: I've never seen a "+ (NSString*)" type function... only the "- (NSString*)" .. with the "+" what do I do, do I need to put it inside a function like viewDidLoad?

Comment: The + just indicates that this method is a *class method*, meaning that it can be called without creating an instance of the class.

Comment: Already I have edited the post to show the entire category for NSFileManager.