# Error when connecting an IBAction to menu item in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, interface-builder

In an objective-c program for mac made in Xcode, I have methods to save and load to and from a save file. These methods worked fine, but when I tried to connect their action to a menubar item (i.e Save and Load under the File menu) the saving stopped working. It ran the method correctly, but it didn't actually save to the save file.

When I disconnected the action from the menubar item and reverted it back to how it was before, it still didn't work correctly.

Is this a bug with Xcode where if you  over right the default save and load actions? Because now my program is broken and I can't find out how to fix it.

The code from the methods are similar to this:

```
- (IBAction)saveGame: (id)sender{ // saving the game
    [self saveAlert];
    NSString *saveFileContents = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%d #%d", int1, int2];
    NSString *file_path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"save" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString *whatWrite = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",saveFileContents];
    [whatWrite writeToFile:file_path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:Nil];
    self.feedLabel.stringValue = @"You just saved";
}


- (IBAction)loadGame: (id)sender{ //loading the save
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"save" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString *aString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:Nil];
    NSMutableArray *substrings = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:aString];
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"#" intoString:nil];

    while(![scanner isAtEnd]) {
        NSString *substring = nil;
        [scanner scanString:@"#" intoString:nil];
        if([scanner scanUpToString:@" " intoString:&substring]) {
            [substrings addObject:substring];
        }
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"#" intoString:nil];
    }

    int1 = [[substrings objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
    int2 = [[substrings objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
}
```

When I run the program and save, it says that is saved and the method `[self saveAlert]` runs as expected. However, when I load, it loads a save file that is the default save file when there is no overwrited save (i.e. when you load without saving first). Therefore, the problem is probably something wrong with the saving?

The code worked perfectly well when I ran it in a separate program, and before I connected the action to the file menu save and load, so I don't think the problem lies there.

Any help would be appreciated, or if you need more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that your existing code doesn't overwrite the save.text file is that an application can not overwrite its resources.

This is the bundle directory containing the application itself. Do not write anything to this directory. To prevent tampering, the bundle directory is signed at installation time. Writing to this directory changes the signature and prevents your application from launching again.

Instead, write to your documents directory. You can get the path to the documents directory like this:

```
NSString * docsDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
```

you just copy your save.text file there as follows

Note that NSHomeDirectory() on iOS simple returns the path to your application's bundle. Once you have the path to the documents directory, you can write to a resource, let's say save.text, as follows:

```
NSString * path = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"save.text"];
[myString writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

From your documents directory you can edit your file as you wish any time while executing.

reference: [-[NSString writeToFile:] does not change the contents of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356352/nsstring-writetofile-does-not-change-the-contents-of-the-file?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Your method worked, but the way I did previously worked up until this point, so what had changed?

Comment: nothing much.. resource files are read only, so you won't able to modify it. The files you creating in home directory of application can be read and write, so you can obviously modify it..